# iOS 13 UIBarButtonItem Font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Wanting to have my own custom font on navigation bar back button items, This worked for me in the past:

```
    let barButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.pink,
                               NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "My-Awesome-Font", size: 18)!]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonAttributes, for: .highlighted)
```

With iOS 13, this has stopped working for me.  Is there a work around?

Comment: does this do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57958270/6459929 ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll want to look into the new `UINavigationBarAppearance` classes in iOS 13.

In your case:

```
let style = UINavigationBarAppearance()
style.buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.font: #YOURFONT#]
style.doneButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.font: #YOURFONT#]

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = style
// You may want these as well:
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = ...
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = ...
```

**Edit:**
Documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

Comment: This worked! `navigationController?` should be `self`, if you are already inside of `UINavigationController`…

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally instead of in each UIViewController?

Comment: @nullforlife `UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = style` works in iOS 13.